# Change a input text with select

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm trying to change an text `input` to a `select` list with mootools when my condition is successful. The problem is that when I use the function `replaces()`, it doesn't work.

```js
window.addEvent('domready', function(event) {
  $('id_x').addEvent('change', function() {
    var idTypeParam = $('param').getSelected().get('value');
    if (idTypeParam == '1') {
      var tmpDiv = new Element('select', {
        html: '<select id="txtQuantity" name="txtQuantity" class="ProductDetailsQuantityTextBox">' +
          '<option value="1">1</option>' +
          '<option value="2">2</option>' +
          '<option value="3">3</option>' +
          '<option value="4">4</option>' +
          '<option value="5">5</option>' +
          '</select>'
      });
      tmpDiv.replaces($('myoldDiv'));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If you're using mootools, why have you tagged this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(event) {
  $('id_x').addEvent('change', function() {
    var idTypeParam = $('param').getSelected().get('value');
    if (idTypeParam == '1') {
      document.getElementById("myoldDiv").innerHTML = '<select id="txtQuantity" name="txtQuantity" class="ProductDetailsQuantityTextBox">' +
          '<option value="1">1</option>' +
          '<option value="2">2</option>' +
          '<option value="3">3</option>' +
          '<option value="4">4</option>' +
          '<option value="5">5</option>' +
          '</select>';
    }
  });
});
```

Or you can use $("myoldDiv").html("")

Comment: i do that but the result still the same

Answer (score 0):

You can append new children of type 'option' to the select

```
const select = new Element('select');
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  select.adopt(new Element('option', {
    html: 'Dynamic Option ' + i,
    value: i
  }));
select.replaces(document.id('myolddiv'));
```